# Auto select the check box in rows

Tags: html, select, checkbox

I am displaying table rows in the form. Each row has 5 columns, one of the columns is an (editable) textbox field.

```
ajaxLoading(true);
    $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>'+"/processServlet", postData,
            function(data) {
              var ctxPath='<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
                currentPosition = data.currentPosition;

                var items = $("#itemsTable");
                items.empty();
                if (data.items.length == 0) {
                    items.append($('<tr><td colspan=5 style="color:red;">No items<td></tr>'));
                }
                ;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {

                    editText = "";

                    items.append($("<tr " + zebra + "><td><a href=\"javascript: deviceView('" + data.items[i].id + "')\">" + data.items[i].num +
                            "</a></td><td>" + data.items[i].itemType +
            "</td><td><input type = 'checkbox' id = 'CheckBoxRow_' />" + data.items[i] +
                            "</td><td><input type = 'textbox' id = 'TextBoxRow_' value = '" + data.items[i].itemName +"' "/>" +
                            "</td><td>" + data.items[i].status +
                            "</td><td>" + data.items[i].date + "</td>" +
                           "<td>" + data.items[i].firmware + "<td>" +
                            "<a href=\"javascript: deleteItem('" + data.items[i].id + "')\">Delete</a>" +
                            "</tr>"));

                ;
                ajaxLoading(false);
            }, "json");
```

How do I auto select the check box when the data is entered or modified in the textbox and save the data in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind to [textbox onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/textbox.onchange) event and have it set the checkbox to checked=true once returned with a value (and not already checked).

```
$('#itemsTable input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e){
  var $cb = $(this);
  if ($cb.is(':checked')){
    $cb.closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"][id^=CheckBoxRow_]').prop('checked','true');
  }
});
```

basically. though you really should not use HTML in an append, and should be building the objects with jQuery.

Comment: how does this reffer to the each row.